# Is moon all natural?

Tags: the-moon, spacecraft, nasa

I really like the science and space related thing and I was reading somewhere on the internet that the Moon is set in place 4.53 billion years ago. So my question is

> **Q:-** Is **Moon** all natural? or is it created by an advanced **extra-terrestrial**
>   ancient civilization?

It may sound stupid but there are some rumors about it that in **1970** 
**NASA** had crashed a spacecraft on the surface of Moon and its surface had vibrated for almost an hour.

Comment: So it seems to me your actual main questions is _"how could the moon vibrate (for this long)"_ on the impact tests? How does the age come into play here, that's about the same age as the earth. Do you want explanations of the most probable theories about how the moon came into existence?

Comment: This question is hard to interpret, are you asking whether ancient aliens made the moon out of synthetic rubber, or something else?

Comment: The question isn't hard to interpret. There's even a wikipedia page on the topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow_Moon . That said, this kind of non-scientific question is very off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 8):

The Moon is natural, just like Earth. In all our studies of the Moon, from Earth, through the Apollo program and through unmanned Moon missions we have found nothing that points to other origins than natural evolution.

NASA has crashed several spacecraft on the Moon, including Apollo rocket stages. With seismometers on the surface, [they found that the moonquakes](https://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2006/15mar_moonquakes/) from those impacts lasted very long (up to an hour, as you say). This is because the composition of the Moon is a bit different from Earth.